# Regular functions on the projective line

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand the following easy (not for me) exercise.

Consider $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ where $k$ is an algebraically closed field.

We have closed points, namely  the ones corresponding to $(a_0x_1-a_1x_0)$, and $\xi$ the generic, corresponding to the trivial ideal.
Then we have that $\kappa(\xi)= k(t)$

Now  I need to say what are the regular functions.

I suppose that regular functions are just the constant functions since $f \in k(t)$ is of the form $p(t)/q(t)$ where $p,q \in k[t]$ and since the field is algebraically closed their zero locus is always different from $0$ unless they are constant.

Is it correct?

Moreover what about the ones of $\mathbb{P}^2_k$?

Comment: Basically yes, if $q$ is not constant, you will have poles at which $f$ is not defined. But what happens if $q$ is constant? Can $p(t)$ be a regular function on $\mathbb P^1$?